# Angular digest apply when setValidation

Tags: angularjs

When I submit a form I do some backend validation to ensure that an email is unique as follows:

```
$http.post('/api/users.json', dataObj)
     .then (function() {
          // we are happy
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
           if(response.data.data.exception) {
                var emailNotUniqueException = 'App\\Http\\Exception\\EmailNotUniqueException'; 
                $scope.userRegister.email.$setValidity("unique", false);
                scrollToFirstError();
            }
      }
);
```

The scrollToFirstError does what is says on the tin:

```
function scrollToFirstError () {
     var invalidInputs = angular.element('input.ng-invalid, select.ng-invalid');
     return invalidInputs.first().focus();
}
```

The problem of course is that although I can see ng-valid has been applied to the input the binding is lost I believe. I read about scope digest and apply, if I add either I get a message:

angular.js:14328 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the validity of a field to invalid, you have to wait until the current digest cycle is applied. If you don't do so, the HTML might be not updated yet when you look for `ng-invalid` classes.

That being said, it is often a good idea to let the digests finish themselves and do not start or invoke them by hand, unless you really know you need this.

In this particular case, I would suggest you to call `scrollToFirstError` in the next digest cycle. It can be simply achieved with the `$timeout` service. Inject it first and then replace your `scrollToFirstError()` call with the following:

```
$timeout(scrollToFirstError);
```